# Composer require 'conclusions' - how to read and fix

Tags: composer-php

i've managed to force my way through composer use for a few years but this is the first time that I've had so many issues trying to install a package.

This is the error, but I have no idea how to start debugging it or what it's evening saying the issue is or how to fix!

```
    - Conclusion: don't install anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.4 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.5 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.13.14 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.13.15 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.13.16 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires anahkiasen/rocketeer ^2.2 -> satisfiable by anahkiasen/rocketeer[2.2.0, ..., 2.2.5].
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.13.1 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of illuminate/container[v8.18.0], anahkiasen/rocketeer[2.2.0] | install one of illuminate/container[v4.2.9, v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.9 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of illuminate/container[v8.18.1], anahkiasen/rocketeer[2.2.0] | install one of illuminate/container[v4.2.12, v4.2.16, v4.2.17] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.12 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of illuminate/container[v8.19.0], anahkiasen/rocketeer[2.2.0] | install one of illuminate/container[v4.2.16, v4.2.17] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.16 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.13.2 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install laravel/valet v2.13.3 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.17 (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of illuminate/container[v8.21.0], anahkiasen/rocketeer[2.2.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of illuminate/container[v8.20.1], anahkiasen/rocketeer[2.2.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - Conclusion: don't install one of illuminate/container[v8.20.0], anahkiasen/rocketeer[2.2.0] (conflict analysis result)
    - laravel/valet[v2.12.0, ..., v2.13.0] require illuminate/container ~5.1|^6.0|^7.0|^8.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.1.1, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.9, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.1, v8.0.0, ..., v8.21.0].
    - laravel/valet[v2.9.0, ..., v2.11.0] require illuminate/container ~5.1 | ^6.0 | ^7.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.1.1, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.9, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.1].
    - laravel/valet[v2.7.0, ..., v2.8.1] require illuminate/container ~5.1 | ^6.0 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v5.1.1, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.9].
    - You can only install one version of a package, so only one of these can be installed: illuminate/container[v4.2.1, ..., v4.2.17, v5.1.1, ..., v5.8.36, v6.0.0, ..., v6.20.9, v7.0.0, ..., v7.30.1, v8.0.0, ..., v8.21.0].
    - anahkiasen/rocketeer 2.2.0 requires illuminate/container ^4.2.7 -> satisfiable by illuminate/container[v4.2.7, ..., v4.2.17].
    - Conclusion: don't install illuminate/container v4.2.8 (conflict analysis result)
    - Root composer.json requires laravel/valet ^2.7 -> satisfiable by laravel/valet[v2.7.0, ..., v2.13.16].
```

Comment: Which command did you run to have this output ? Which dependency did you try to add ?

Answer (score 0):

Even if I don't really get your question: I think the problem is that you require `anahkiasen/rocketeer` (which is not compatible with anything more recent than Laravel v4) and `laravel/valet` in anything matching `^2.7`, which requires at leat Laravel v5.1.

How to resolve this is up to you - but as that Rocketeer package is really outdated and no longer maintained, I would start by looking for an alternative.

Next time, you should require packages one by one. You would have seen that these two package contraints can not work together